# Swift - JSONDecoder - passing class Type as parameter to decode model using generic method

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols, jsondecoder

### Here, we have a scenario where I am facing issue for parsing the model class using "JSONDecoder".

Let me share you what I have done in this example and where I am facing issue:

- There's a model protocol derived through the Codable.
- A struct model and A class GenericExample
- GenericExample class have following things:

  - shared instance
  - typeContainer which is the type of Protocol
- There's two more methods **staticClassParsing** and **dynamicClassParsing** with one parameter dynamicType
- In the last, One generic method which return the parsed data model.

**Calling method for parsing the model:**

> GenericExample.shared.dynamicClassParsing(Numbers.self,data: "[\r\n{\"one\": \"1\"},\r\n{\"two\":\"2\"}\r\n]")

**Compile Time Error:**

> ***Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred***

**Occurred here**

> ***returnModelType: typeContainer.self***

**For more details, please go through following code: **

```
protocol BaseMapModel : Codable { }
```

```
struct Numbers: BaseMapModel {
    var one: String?
    var two: String?
}
```

```
class GenericExample: NSObject {

    static let shared = GenericExample()

    var typeContainer : BaseMapModel.Type?

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

```
extension GenericExample {

    // Static Class Parsing passed through the conversion
    func staticClassParsing() {
        let dataJson = "[\r\n{\"one\": \"1\"},\r\n{\"two\":\"2\"}\r\n]"
        convertTypeContainer(data: Data(dataJson.utf8), returnModelType: Numbers.self) { (mappedResult) in
            print(mappedResult?.one ?? "")
            print(mappedResult?.two ?? "")
        }
    }

    // Dynamic Class Parsing can't passed through the conversion
    // Error:- Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
    // Error Parameter:- in "returnModelType: typeContainer.self"
    func dynamicClassParsing(_ dynamicType: BaseMapModel.Type, data:String) {
        typeContainer = dynamicType.self
        convertTypeContainer(data: Data(data.utf8), returnModelType: typeContainer.self) { (mappedResult) in
            print(mappedResult?.one ?? "")
            print(mappedResult?.two ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```

```
extension GenericExample {

    private func convertTypeContainer<T : BaseMapModel>(data:Data, returnModelType: T.Type, completion: ((_ result:T?)->Void)) {

        guard let responseModel = try? JSONDecoder().decode(returnModelType.self, from: data) else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        completion(responseModel)
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `dynamicClassParsing`? Why is that extra layer needed?

Comment: In my code, we have one APIServiceHandler class where I have a method like convertTypeContainer and one more ModuleHanlder with 3 consecutive API calls on particular actions. Initial 2 calls have fixed response and it’s url end points however, last and final API have different response and it’s url endpoint. So that’s why I need this.

Comment: How are you planning to use this for the last API, how are you going to call dynamicClassParsing? You still need to know the type to call dynamicClassParsing with?

Comment: Do you want to create common method which will parse all Codable?

Answer (score 2):

`typeContainer` must be a concrete type, it cannot be a protocol. And the completion handler is pointless as `JSONDecoder` works synchronously.

To decode JSON with generics you have to use something like this, it's highly recommended to handle also the Decoding error

```
struct Numbers: Decodable {
    var one: String?
    var two: String?
}

class GenericExample: NSObject {
    static let shared = GenericExample()
}

extension GenericExample {
    func dynamicClassParsing<T : Decodable>(_ dynamicType: T.Type, data: String) -> Result<T,Error> {
        return Result { try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: Data(data.utf8)) }
    }
}

let dataJson = """
[{"one": "1"},{"two":"2"}]
"""

let result = GenericExample.shared.dynamicClassParsing([Numbers].self, data: dataJson)
switch result {
    case .success(let numbers): print(numbers)
    case .failure(let error): print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts vadian. still my question is open, I want to decode only through the `typeContainer` which accepting `protocol.Type`. Please help me for this if we have some solutions. :)

Comment: What is unclear with *`typeContainer` must be a concrete type*?

Comment: Do we have anything documented for the same?, Like it should concreteType?

Comment: `JSONDecoder` relies on concrete types. That's a fact. According to the [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895189-decode) the first parameter of `decode` must be a concrete type which conforms to `Decodable`

Comment: Yes, you are right @vadian. It should concrete types. I have solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all, Thanks to All for your support. And Yes, I would like to post answer to my question.**

```
class BaseMapModel : Codable { }

class Numbers: BaseMapModel {
    var one: String?
    var two: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case one = "one"
        case two = "two"
    }

    // Decoding
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let response = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        one = try? response.decode(String.self, forKey: .one)
        two = try? response.decode(String.self, forKey: .two)

        let superDecoder = try response.superDecoder()
        try super.init(from: superDecoder)
    }
}

class GenericExample: NSObject {

    static let shared = GenericExample()

    var defaultTypeContainer : Numbers.Type!

    var typeContainer : BaseMapModel.Type?

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}

extension GenericExample {

    // Static Class Parsing passed through the conversion
    func staticClassParsing() {
        let dataJson = "[\r\n{\"one\": \"1\"},\r\n{\"two\":\"2\"}\r\n]"
        convertTypeContainer(data: Data(dataJson.utf8), returnModelType: Numbers.self) { (mappedResult) in
            print(mappedResult?.one ?? "")
            print(mappedResult?.two ?? "")
        }
    }

    // Dynamic Class Parsing passed through the conversion
    func dynamicClassParsing(_ dynamicType: BaseMapModel.Type, data:String) {
        typeContainer = dynamicType.self
        convertTypeContainer(data: Data(data.utf8), returnModelType: (typeContainer ?? defaultTypeContainer).self) { (mappedResult) in
            print((mappedResult as? Numbers)?.one ?? "")
            print((mappedResult as? Numbers)?.two ?? "")
        }
    }
}

extension GenericExample {

    private func convertTypeContainer<T : BaseMapModel>(data:Data, returnModelType: T.Type, completion: ((_ result:T?)->Void)) {

        guard let responseModel = try? JSONDecoder().decode(returnModelType.self, from: data) else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        completion(responseModel)
    }
}
```